# org-mode: How to export underscore as underscore instead of highlight in HTML?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I am using `org-mode`, and the document I am writing has a table name whose name looks like this: `tab_weekly_report`. When I export the document to HTML, I expect the name to exported as `tab_weekly_report`, but `org-mode` treats `_` specially (as a markup character). How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## `org-mode` exports `_` as subscripts and `^` as superscripts

The default export behavior can be [customized](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-customize.html) using the menus `Org -> Customize -> Browse Org Group`.
To update the default behavior for subscripts & superscripts, choose:

- [-]-\ Group Org Export

  - [-]-\ Group Org Export General

    - — Option Org Export With Sub Superscripts

## Org Export With Sub Superscripts Examples

### Examples

1. Interpret them - Default

   - Underscore_subscript becomes Underscore<sub>subscript</sub>
   - Hat^superscript becomes Hat<sup>superscript</sup>
2. Curly brackets only

   - Underscore_WithCurlyBrackets_{subscript} becomes Underscore_WithCurlyBrackets<sub>subscript</sub>
   - Hat^WithCurlyBrackets^{superscript} becomes Hat^WithCurlyBrackets<sup>superscript</sup>
3. Do not interpret them

   - Underscore_subscript becomes Underscore_subscript
   - Hat^superscript becomes Hat^superscript
   - Underscore_WithCurlyBrackets_{subscript} becomes Underscore_WithCurlyBrackets_{subscript}
   - Hat^WithCurlyBrackets^{superscript} becomes Hat^WithCurlyBrackets^{superscript}

> **Note:** If you don't want to mess around with settings, the quick and easy solution is to disable superscripts and subscripts by setting export option for `^` to `nil`.
>
> - To disable superscripts and subscripts, add the following lines to your org file:
>
>   ```
>   #+OPTIONS: ^:nil
>   ```

Comment: AFAIK, there is no `_` option. The `^` option is called `org-export-with-sub-superscripts` internally, indicating that it affects both.

Comment: @NickD - Thanks for catching nonexistent `_` option! I’ve removed it from answer.

Comment: Is there a way to have subscripts enabled but escape the underlines? `\_` doesn't work, which does in LaTeX.

Comment: @HappyFace - I use and recommend using `#OPTIONS: ^{}` which leaves underscores and hats alone and makes the syntax `^{superscript}` and `_{subscript}` instead.

Comment: @Melioratus As pointed out by a news user who doesn't how comment rights, there is a colon missing between the caret and the braces, so it should be `^:{}` instead of `^{}`, as in the answer of Joseph Tesfaye.

Comment: Thank you.
I am exporting SQL queries, and table results.
I have "low line"* in some of my column names.
This paper doesn't require subscript, so the simple fix works.

Answer (score 27):

Add the following at the beginning of your file.

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil
```

It should do the trick. If it doesn't, I'd check org-symbols: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-symbols.html

Answer (score 19):

Somewhat hard to find, but you can just use `foo \under foo` or `foo\under{}foo`.

Comment: Brilliant! thanks.

Comment: This should be the best (most upvoted) answer

Answer (score 4):

By default the underscore "_" and caret "^" characters are treated as markers of subscripts and superscripts when exporting with org-mode or pandoc. To export them as they are you can add the line

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:{}
```

to your org file and then use either org-mode or pandoc to export. If you are using [pandoc-mode](https://github.com/joostkremers/pandoc-mode) make sure the region to be exported also include this line before the underscore and caret characters.

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing and refining @Melioratus answer/commentary (which is the currently  -- 2022-12-07 -- the top and accepted answer)

You can add this directive to your file to prevent underscores getting interpreted as subscripts.

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil
```

...or even better, this...

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:{}
```

@Melioratus had mentioned the latter in a comment but it did not work for me.  Experimentation has shown that if I change @Melioratus's comment from...

```
#OPTIONS: ^{}
```

...to...

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:{}
```

...then it works as described.

Comment: Welcome, but sorry the rules of the site don't encourage answers of this type that should be comments.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead  .  I'll a note below the other comment mentioning this, but the correct syntax is already given in another answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/23334)

Comment: I saw the comment in the post about answering in the comments - please don't answer in comments - answer with an actual answer. - Can you address the concerns about this answer not actually addressing the question? If not, this answer is likely to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include it in your config directly, instead of setting the option in each file:

```
(setq org-use-sub-superscripts nil)
(setq org-export-with-sub-superscripts nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change Org-mode behavior globally on your document, use the `=` symbol:

```
=tab_weekly_report=
```